# NameError: name "AnyName" is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do an N-Ary tree based on Linked-Lists and Nodes. But whenever I try to add a new value to the tree I keep getting:

**NameError: name 'self' is not defined**

I work with modules so I have to import the classes from other files.

I get this error in **def addTree(self, value, parent = self.root):** on Tree Code

**Tree Code**

```
from Resources.LinkedList import *

class Tree:
def __init__(self):
    self.root = LinkedList()

def addTree(self, value, parent = self.root):
    parent.addLinkedList(value)
```

**Node Code**

```
from Resources.LinkedList import *

class Node:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.children = LinkedList()
        self.next = None
```

**Linked-List Code**

```
from Resources.Node import *
from Resources.Compare import *

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None

    def addLinkedList(self,value):
        if (not self.first):
            self.first = Node(value)
        else:
            compare = Compare()
            if(compare.compare(self.first,value)>0):
                stack = self.first
                self.first = Node(value)
                self.first.next = stack
                return True
            else:
                previous = self.first
                current = self.first.next

                while(current):
                    if (compare.compare(current,value)<0):
                        previous = current
                        current = current.next
                         return True
                    elif (compare.compare(current,value)>0):
                        stack = current
                        previous.next = Node(value)
                        previous.next.next = stack
                        return True
                    else:
                        previous.next = Node(value)
                        previous.next.next = current.next
                        return True

                previous.next = Node(value)
                return True
```

Also thanks for your help, I'm kinda new to Python and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that "self" is only defined within the method and cannot be used in the arguments, the trick in these cases is to use None as an argument and make the verification:

```py
def addTree(self, value, parent = None):
    if parent is None:
        parent = self.root
    parent.addLinkedList(value)
```